# count different plant types in a r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have the following dataset, where p1 is the number of plant species indicated by column sp1, and p2 is the number of plant species indicated by column sp2, and so on. I want to create a new variable named Count1 for example, which counts the total number of wheat species in each row and paste it into the new variable Count1. For example in row 9 (ID=7), we have 7 wheat plants in total or in row 7 (ID=5), we don't have any wheat, so it will be 0 in Count1 variable. I would appreciate if you help me to solve this.

```
plt <- data.frame(ID = c(0:10), p1 = c(1,1,1,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,4), 
                  sp1 = c('wheat', 'wheat', 'wheat', 'barley','barley',
                          'barley','barley','barley', 'rice','rice','rice'), 
                  p2 = c(0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
                  sp2 = c(0,0,0,'rice', 'rice', 'rice', 'rice', 'wheat',
                        'wheat', 'wheat','wheat'), 
                  p3 = c(0,0,2,2,2,2, 5,5,5,5,5), 
                  sp3= c(0,0,0, 'rice', 'rice', 'rice', 'wheat', 'wheat',
                         'wheat', 'wheat', 'wheat'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` with `paste` to check your condition and subsequently apply the sum

```
plt$Count1 <- rowSums(sapply(1:length(grep("^sp",colnames(plt))), function(x) 
  ifelse(plt[, paste0("sp", x)] == "wheat", plt[, paste0("p", x)], 0)))

plt
   ID p1    sp1 p2   sp2 p3   sp3 Count1
1   0  1  wheat  0     0  0     0      1
2   1  1  wheat  0     0  0     0      1
3   2  1  wheat  0     0  2     0      1
4   3  8 barley  2  rice  2  rice      0
5   4  8 barley  2  rice  2  rice      0
6   5  8 barley  2  rice  2  rice      0
7   6  8 barley  2  rice  5 wheat      5
8   7  8 barley  2 wheat  5 wheat      7
9   8  4   rice  2 wheat  5 wheat      7
10  9  4   rice  2 wheat  5 wheat      7
11 10  4   rice  2 wheat  5 wheat      7
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` you could try the following. First, put your data in long form with `pivot_longer`, and remove rows where `sp` is zero.

Then, for each `ID` and `sp`, total up the sum of `p`. You can then put the data into wide form again if desired, and join back to original data. This will calculate sum of each type (wheat, barley, rice).

```
library(tidyverse)

plt %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value", "number"), names_pattern = "(p|sp)(\\d+)") %>%
  filter(sp != 0) %>%
  group_by(ID, sp) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(p)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = sp, values_from = total, values_fill = 0) %>%
  right_join(plt)
```

**Output**

```
      ID wheat barley  rice    p1 sp1       p2 sp2      p3 sp3  
   <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1     0     1      0     0     1 wheat      0 0         0 0    
 2     1     1      0     0     1 wheat      0 0         0 0    
 3     2     1      0     0     1 wheat      0 0         2 0    
 4     3     0      8     4     8 barley     2 rice      2 rice 
 5     4     0      8     4     8 barley     2 rice      2 rice 
 6     5     0      8     4     8 barley     2 rice      2 rice 
 7     6     5      8     2     8 barley     2 rice      5 wheat
 8     7     7      8     0     8 barley     2 wheat     5 wheat
 9     8     7      0     4     4 rice       2 wheat     5 wheat
10     9     7      0     4     4 rice       2 wheat     5 wheat
11    10     7      0     4     4 rice       2 wheat     5 wheat
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a non efficient method, but it's more "intuitive". Ben and Andre's answers are a better solution since its compactness and, probably, its performance.

However, this is the idea:

```
word <- "wheat" # take class you want
indexes <- which(plt==word,arr.ind = TRUE) # find indices in matrix which contains that word
new_matrix <- subset(plt,is.element(row.names(plt),unique(indexes[,1]))==TRUE) # subset that matrix

count_w <- 0; k <- 1;rowcounts <- c();

for (j in 1:nrow(new_matrix)){ # loop by rows
  a <- which(new_matrix[j,]==word) # which columns contains the value "word"?
  for (i in a){
    count_w <- count_w + new_matrix[j,i-1] # Just sum the columns
  }
  rowcounts[k] <- count_w # save the counts
  count_w <- 0; # and start again for another row
  k <- k+1
}

Count_1 <- rep(0,nrow(plt));p <- 1

for (k in sort(unique(indexes[,1]))){ # To be consistent with original data frame, new column of counts must have same dimension, so let's fill it with zeros and substitute with counts vector
  Count_1[k] <- rowcounts[p]
  p <- p+1;
}

final_matrix <- cbind(plt,Count_1) # just combine
```

You can see that 23 lines of code (in my case) can be substituted with fewer ones (see Ben & Andre's answers)!